# Post data from VBscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a function that need to accept two parameters- user and folder! I call that function from VBscript, and parameters need to be send with post method.  This is the Vbscript function code from where I want to post data:

```
Sub loadDocument()
Const HOST = "http://192.168.0.144/webservice13/service1.asmx/Lock?User="& PC\User & "folder="&c:\foldername
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.open  "POST",HOST 
xmlhttp.send ""
End Sub
```

Now when i try to execute this function i getting error message that i have syntax error!
I assume that error is in this line:

```
Const HOST = "http://192.168.0.144/webservice13/service1.asmx/Lock?User="& PC\User & "folder="&c:\foldername
```

How I can resolve this, how i can post two variables to this function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot declare a Const variable with variable parts. Change the line to

```
dim userVar, folderVar, HOST

userVar = "PC\User"
folderVar = "c:\foldername"

HOST = "http://192.168.0.144/webservice13/service1.asmx/Lock?User=" & userVar & "&folder=" & folderVar
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the `PC\User` and `c:\foldername` paremeters you are using when constructing your `HOST` variable are propery [URL Encoded](http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/urlEncoding/)?

You should also prepend an `&` to any additional parameter. You have not done this with your `"folder="` paramenter, which should be `"&folder="`.

Comment: All parameters are properly encoded. But somewhere in syntax a have error!